# Disable future dates in magento datepicker

Tags: magento-1.9, date, datepicker

I am using magento datepicker. i have an array dates which i want to disable that days in the magento datepicked.

for example 08/29/14 is holiday. so i want to make the date as disable so the user cannot select that.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that this is a custom module, take a look at [Magento calendar: Datepicker issue to disable days before today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635106/magento-calendar-datepicker-issue-to-disable-days-before-today)

```
Calendar.setup({
    inputField : 'date',
    ifFormat : '%e/%m/%Y',
    button : 'date_from_trig',
    align : 'Bl',
    singleClick : true,
    dateStatusFunc : disabledDate 
});

function disabledDate(date) {
    var today = new Date();
    return ([date1, date2, ..].indexOf(date.getDate()) !== -1) ? true : false;
};
```

[Array#indexOf](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/prototype/indexOf/)

Comment: i have 2 function one above disabling future dates and one disabling the past days.how can i call this 2 functions at a time.

Comment: Did you try combining both function. if date not > or date not < return true else false

Comment: i was checking like this  dateStatusFunc : disabledDate , pastdays,   giving me the err

Comment: where this code will going to place? I have scenario for purchase order date. I want to disable past date disable in magento 2. what i have to do?

Comment: @PramodKharade ... for Magento 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @ Renon Stewart  magento 2.1.4

Comment: @PramodKharade ... I have not tried this in M2 yet ... I could be wrong but I was under the impression that M2 uses a jQuery datepicker ... see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146448/how-to-add-datepicker-in-magento-2-frontend-form ... also take a look at https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: Please create a new question with more info/sample code and I will take a look at it