# Disable date not working in magento 1.9 frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, datepicker

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
Calendar.setup({
inputField : 'shipping_arrival_date',
ifFormat : '%m-%d-%Y',
showsTime: false,
button : 'shipping_arrival_date_trig',
 align: "Bl",
singleClick : true,
dateStatusFunc : disabledDate,


disableFunc: function(date) {
//disable previous day in datepicker
var now= new Date();
if(date.getFullYear()<now.getFullYear())
{
return true;
}
if(date.getFullYear()==now.getFullYear())
{
if(date.getMonth()<now.getMonth())
{
return true;
}
}
if(date.getMonth()==now.getMonth())
{
if(date.getDate()<now.getDate())
{
return true;
}
}
},
});

function disabledDate(date) {
    var today = new Date();
    return (["3-12-2019", "3-15-2019"].indexOf(date.getDate()) !== -1) ? true : false;
};
// ]]>
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: try this way.. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33536/68695

Comment: i will try and update u @rakesh

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: `beforeShowDay`? Are you using a jQuery Datepicker widget? Otherwise `dateStatusFunc` should be correct imho.

Comment: I was tried it your info but it was not working for me @HelgeB

Comment: @divyasekar i think you have wrong implement

Comment: what was wrong with a code @rakesh

Comment: @divyasekar check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way...

```
 function disabledDate(date) {
    var disableddates = ["3-23-2019", "3-20-2019"];

     var m = date.getMonth();
     var d = date.getDate();
     var y = date.getFullYear();

     // First convert the date in to the mm-dd-yyyy format 
     // Take note that we will increment the month count by 1 
     var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;

      // We will now check if the date belongs to disableddates array 
     for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {

     // Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array. 
     if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
     return [false];
     }
     }

    }
```

Comment: you have which code apply?

Comment: i tried a second way it gives error https://prnt.sc/my4g78

Comment: i have tested first way working for me

Comment: i tried both way 1st one shows nothing  2nd one reflects https://prnt.sc/my4g78

Comment: s i have change the format

Comment: i was replace a $ with jQuery, error was clear but disable dates not working

Answer (score 2):

Update Answer  for disabled dates, day and  previous past dates
it's working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dayoff = '<?php echo $dayoff; ?>';
// <![CDATA[
Calendar.setup({
inputField : 'shipping_arrival_date',
ifFormat : '%m-%e-%Y',
showsTime: false,
button : 'shipping_arrival_date_trig',
 align: "Bl",
singleClick : true,

disableFunc: function(date) {

               var now = new Date();
                var y = calendar.date.getFullYear();
                var m = calendar.date.getMonth();     
                var d = calendar.date.getDate();
                var day_off_array = dayoff.split(",") ;
                currentTime = new Date();
                var d1=currentTime.getDate();
                var m1=currentTime.getMonth();
                var y1=currentTime.getFullYear();
                var counter = 1;
                var disabledDays = ["3-20-2019", "3-26-2019"];

     var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
      for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
      var dd = (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y;
     if(disabledDays.indexOf(dd) != -1) {
        return true;
       }
    }
                for (var i=0; i<day_off_array.length;i++){
                    if (day_off_array[i]>=0 && day_off_array[i]!=''){
                        if (date.getDay()==day_off_array[i]){
                            if (date.getDate()==currentTime.getDate()){
                                test_flag=true;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(y < y1)
                    {
                    return true;
                }
                else if(m1 > m && y==y1)
                    {
                    return true;
                }

            if(date.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()){
                return true;
            }
            if(date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() < now.getMonth()){
                return true;
            }
            if(date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() < now.getDate()){
                return true;
            } 

    }


});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: my second way is right only date formate wrong

Comment: yes @rakesh  i accept your answer

Comment: thanks @divya my pleasure!!